# Problem with float values in json. The values are interpreted with two elements of the array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a problem calling an external API, Sendgrid, to validate email addresses, when I  working on my package [abkrim/sendgrid](https://packagist.org/packages/abkrim/sendgrid)

The API client based on an (official) Sendgrid library for PHP (laravel), returns an element of the response with a float value. (Pay attention to the value score)

I call a one endpoint and get this body

```json
{
    "result": {
        "email": "jhjhkjhkjhjhksdas3@gmail.com",
        "verdict": "Risky",
        "score": 0.06393,
        "local": "jhjhkjhkjhjhksdas3",
        "host": "gmail.com",
        "checks": {
            "domain": {
                "has_valid_address_syntax": true,
                "has_mx_or_a_record": true,
                "is_suspected_disposable_address": false
            },
            "local_part": {
                "is_suspected_role_address": false
            },
            "additional": {
                "has_known_bounces": false,
                "has_suspected_bounces": true
            }
        },
        "ip_address": "0.0.0.0"
    }
}
```

And convert to array

```php
"result" => [
    "email" => "jhjhkjhkjhjhksdas3@gmail.com",
    "verdict" => "Risky",
    "score" => 0.06393,0
    "local" => "jhjhkjhkjhjhksdas3",
    "host" => "gmail.com",
    "checks" => [
       "domain" => [
           "has_valid_address_syntax" => true,
           "has_mx_or_a_record" => true,
           "is_suspected_disposable_address" => false,
         ],
         "local_part" => [
           "is_suspected_role_address" => false,
         ]
         "additional" => [
           "has_known_bounces" => false,
           "has_suspected_bounces" => true,
         ],
       ],
    ],
    "ip_address" => "0.0.0.0",
]
```

To execute a foreach in this array I need to do one thing since the score value is interpreted as two array elements, the normal one, that is score and its value, and another element with the key equal to 0 and the value equal to 0.

### Testing

```php
/** @test */
function underscored_array_is_converted_on_normal_array()
{
    $array = [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2"
        "key3" => 0.9998,0
        "upperkey1_subkey1_final__one__element" => true,
        "upperkey1_subkey1_final__two__element" => false,
        "key4" => "1.1.1.1",
    ];

    $result = General::normalizeArray($array);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('upperkey1', $result);
}
```

### Helper class and method

```php
public static function normalizeArray(array $array): array
{
    $new = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (($key == $value) && ($key == 0)) continue; // Work around for problem value float
        $newkey = str_replace('#', '_', str_replace('_', '.', str_replace('__', '#', $key)));
        $new[$newkey] = $value;
    }

    return Arr::undot($new);
}
```

If dump on my test $result get a value `"key3" => 0.9998,0`

If not use `if (($key == $value) && ($key == 0)) continue;` I get a new element on array, because `score` converts onto two elements, one for score and other for key 0, value 0.

That's is normal?
Exists any way for work with array with float values?

Comment: Use `===` to ensure the two values are the same and of the same type. Otherwise a string key may be coerced to a numeric value and as such will have a value of 0 which may not be what you want

Comment: Thank you, but the question is not related to why I put == in the solution, but because the values of a json key with float values are interpreted with that value, and the problem that arises when doing a foreach in the array.
If you do not make a strict purchase, it is for another question. Thank you @apokryfos

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/994719bcddcd8fa055905f43686c551a35ca116a) it looks like it produces what I expect it

Comment: I've a mistake on post. When convert json response to array with json_decode, array has convert key "key3" => 0.9998,0 with ,o at end. This created a problem on foreach, because aray has a new key "0" with value 0.

Comment: Need to carefully audit the JSON string you are receiving for potential hidden characters or check (and maybe share) how you're decoding the JSON because again [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec4cf4fee19d349ebd03c37c86e90e28665825fe) I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Use var_dump to show the json string and the decoded array, I can't believe json_decode could produce the strange `,0` as result.

Answer (score 0):

When applying `print_r(json_decode($json, true))` to your json it returns:

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [email] => jhjhkjhkjhjhksdas3@gmail.com
            [verdict] => Risky
            [score] => 0.06393
            [local] => jhjhkjhkjhjhksdas3
...
```

There is no `,0` at the end.

In your testing example you did add `,0` to the end of `key3`. This part:

```
    $array = [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "key3" => 0.9998,0,
        "upperkey1_subkey1_final__one__element" => true,
```

Is similar to doing:

```
    $array = [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        "key3" => 0.9998,
        0 => 0,
        "upperkey1_subkey1_final__one__element" => true,
```

Your adding an element to the array without specifying the key, so PHP numerates it for you.

Comment: I don't add any thing. 0.9999,0 is value return after json_decode data of api response to array format.  That is the problem. Testing is for testing. Please read first part of post.